# Proxifying a url in php

Tags: php, proxy

I want to create a web proxy with PHP.

I generate an url (e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/file.mp3`).

Now instead of showing the url to my users , I want to create a "proxy" version of the url (e.g. `http://mydomain.com/someramndomchars/file.mp3`). Take note that file.mp3 will not be stored on my server but will simply act as a proxy between `stackoverflow.com` and the user. This way if http://stackoverflow.com domain is blocked for my users, they will still be able to download file.mp3 through my proxy and consequently evade censorship.

Any idea how i can accomplish it with PHP?

Comment: Install a proxy on your domain. Check `squid` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this tool:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/php-proxy/

Basically it's really simple:

1. A user POSTs the requested url to your site
2. You make a request to the site (server side) and print the received content to the user.

But the problem is that much site makes AJAX request or load files from other servers. You have to catch this requests and redirect them over your proxy server, what can be very difficult with PHP.

Comment: Thanks but i understand how proxy work but i want to deliver a proxify the url that my site generated and just provide an alternate download link to user.A full fledge proxy script is overkill , just looking for something simple

Comment: Well, if you understand how a proxy works this can't be to hard for you. Go and try. If you need more help you could try to clarify your question, what's exactly the problem for you.